# How to create cats IO monad from cats State

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I am working with cats and I want to transform my `val x: State[A, B]` to `StateT[IO, A, B]`. Note: IO is from cats-effects.

How to do this elegantly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `mapK` in combination with `cats.arrow.FunctionK.lift`:

```
x.mapK(lift(IO.eval))
```

Full compilable code snippet:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.data.{State, StateT}
import cats.arrow.FunctionK.lift

object InjectIdIO {
  def i[S, V](x: State[S, V]): StateT[IO, S, V] = x.mapK(lift(IO.eval))
}
```

This works because `State[S, A]` is actually `StateT[Eval, S, A]`, and you want to replace the `Eval` by `IO` - this is what the `mapK` is usually for.

---

Another alternative with `kind-projector`:

```
x.mapK(Lambda[Eval ~> IO](IO.eval(_)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
def liftState[A, B](state: State[A, B]): StateT[IO, A, B] =
  StateT[IO, A, B] { s => IO.eval(state.run(s)) }
```

for example

```
val x: State[Int, String] = State(int => (int, "foo"))
liftState(x)
```